# Criar uma nova tabela para valores opcionais

Tags: mysql, tabela-banco-de-dados, tabela-html, relacionamento, null

Tem algum problema criar uma nova tabela para campos que não sejam obrigatórios ? Por exemplo na tabela endereco(cod_endereco, logradouro, cep, numero, complemento) onde complemento e um campo opcional, e quando um usuario inserir dados a tabela não fique com esse campo nulo, e quando o usuario inserir um complemento ele ser usado em uma nova tabela. Não tenho certeza mas campos nulos ou vazios ocupam espaço, e quero evitar a que o espaço seja ocupado por esses campos 'em branco'. A primeira imagem mostra a tabela endereco(cod_endereco not null, logradouro not null, cep not null, numero not null, complemento null), a segunda ja e com duas tabelas onde a tabela complemento só será preenchida caso o usuario informe o complemento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Mysql é suficientemente "esperto" para ocupar pouco espaço por campos nulos. Portanto, criar uma tabela auxiliar apenas para registrar campos opcionais, além de ser trabalhoso, poderá ocupar ainda mais espaço do que se apenas deixasse os campos vazios dentro da tabela, sem contar que ainda diminuirá a performance pois o banco precisará consultar duas tabelas ao invés de apenas uma.

Deixando os campos com `NULL` fará com que o MySQL possa interpreta-lo melhor e reduzir o uso de espaço:

Traduzindo um trecho de https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-physical-record.html:

> Um valor SQL NULL reserva um ou dois bytes no diretório de registro.
>   Além disso, um valor SQL NULL reserva zero bytes na parte de dados do
>   registro, se armazenado em uma coluna de tamanho variável. Em uma
>   coluna de tamanho fixo, ela reserva o tamanho fixo da coluna na parte
>   de dados do registro. A reserva do espaço fixo para valores NULL
>   permite que uma atualização da coluna de NULL para um valor não-NULL
>   seja feita no local sem causar a fragmentação da página de índice.

Comment: Tem alguns detalhes que podem ser confusos pra trabalhar com NULL, mas isso aí.

Comment: Muito obrigado ! Realmente o que me preocupava era a questão do espaço e do desempenho. Tirou uma duvida que me encomodava a algum tempo.